# Lodash. How to get aggregate array from array objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

For example, I have an array:

```
const reference = [{id: 1, value: 10}, {id: 2, value: 10}, {id: 3, value: 10}, {id: 4, value: 5}];
```

How to get an array values from **reference** like

```
const result = [0, 10, 20, 25];
```

First step always = 0

Second step 0 + 10 = 10

Third step 0 + 10 + 10 = 20

Forth step 0 + 10 + 10 + 5 = 25

Comment: what happened to the third ten? First element always gets considered as zero?

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes it's true. First always zero.

Comment: Why is there no `30` in the output array? Shouldn't the output array have `reference.length + 1` items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the values by taking a closure over the sum and take zero for the first element.

```js
const
    reference = [{ id: 1, value: 10 }, { id: 2, value: 10 }, { id: 3, value: 10 }, { id: 4, value: 5 }],
    result = reference.map((sum => ({ value }, i) => sum += i && value)(0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the array, and add the current `value` to the last sum:

```js
const reference = [{id: 1, value: 10}, {id: 2, value: 10}, {id: 3, value: 10}, {id: 4, value: 5}];

const result = reference
  .reduce((r, o, i) => {
    r.push(i === 0 ? 0 : r[r.length - 1] + o.value);
    
    return r;
  }, [])
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be by using the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method as follows :

```js
let result = [0]

reference.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    result.push(Object.values(cur)[1]+result[result.length-1])
})
```

Hope it helps